# Security differences between add jar libraries and include the src of the libraries

Tags: android, proguard, android-library, java

If I want to distribute a closed paid app, there are differences in decompilation if

**a)** I compile the code of the library directly with a copy-paste of the src classes in my project

**b)** I simply add the .jar of the library to my build path

**c)** I create an android library project and add it to my main project

I have heard that the only advantage of **a)** is that obfuscators like proguard can obfuscate the whole library code while in **b)** this is not possible since the classes are yet compiled.... Is this info correct?

and in **c)** ? is the same case of **a)** or there is any difference in code security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options all produce the same results. ProGuard reads the compiled code from the application project, from any library jars, and from any library projects, and treats it all the same.